# Overriding equals and hashcode java

Tags: java, overriding, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

```
package testpack;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestEm {

    private String company;
    private int salary;

    TestEm(String company, int salary) {
        this.company = company;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<TestEm, String> map = new HashMap<TestEm, String>();
        map.put(new TestEm("abc", 100), "emp1");
        map.put(new TestEm("def", 200), "emp2");
        map.put(new TestEm("ghi", 300), "emp3");

        Set<TestEm> set = map.keySet();
        Iterator<TestEm> it = set.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
        **System.out.println(map.get(new TestEm("ghi", 300)));**

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof TestEm))
            return false;

        TestEm te = (TestEm) o;
        return te.company.equals(company) && te.salary == salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        int code = 0;

        code = salary * 10;
        return code;
    }

    /*
     * @Override public String toString() {
     * 
     *    return this.company;  }
     */
}
```

**and the output is**

```
testpack.TestEm@3e8
testpack.TestEm@7d0
testpack.TestEm@bb8
emp3
```

Hi, i have overridden some methods of Object class in my TestEm class, everything is okay but first three outputs are using iterator and then doing a S.O.P and the last one is simply with S.O.P, i just want to know that why first three outputs are coming as objects using iterator and the 4th one simply the correct output as value corresponding the key, i have not overridden toString() so first three outputs are right but then without toString() how S.O.P is showing the correct output.

Comment: What do you mean by "S.O.P."? (This isn't an acronym I'm familiar with...)

Comment: @JonSkeet at a guess `System.out.println`

Comment: @Jon yes it is System.out.println(), i believe its pretty common acronym :p

Comment: @ParitoshAhuja: The fact that I haven't come across it often enough to recognize it despite answering over 6000 questions tagged "java" suggests it's not *that* common. I think it would be clearer to just write "printing" instead of "doing a S.O.P.".

Comment: It's also not clear what the question is - why do you believe that `toString()` is relevant, and as you've overridden `equals` and `hashCode` why would you expect the final output to be *incorrect*?

Comment: okay, i will prefer writing printing instead of S.O.P :) , talking about this question, if i wont override toString() then i wont get correct output using Iterator because iterator as said by NPE, iterates over the entire object so at the output i get entire object but i wanted to have name or salary or combination of both that was possible only with toString().

Comment: Not really - it's that with the iterator you're printing the keys from the map; in the last case you're printing the value in the map. It's not a matter of "the entire object"... (If you change to use `values()` instead of `keySet()` you'll get the "emp1", "emp2", "emp3".)

Comment: yep yep got that thanks for the help :)

Comment: This question is not about hashCode and equals. It is about the semantics of a Map.

Answer (score 3):

The iterator iterates over the objects in the set, whereas

```
map.get(new TestEm("ghi", 300))
```

returns the value associated with the above key. That value is `"emp3"`.

Comment: and the objects in the set are the keys of the map (I know that's fairly obvious, but it seemed to be worth mentioning anyway :p)

Answer (score 1):

The iterator is traversing and printing the *keys* (class: `TestEm`), whereas the S.O.P on the outside is retrieving a *value* of the map, corresponding to the key `TestEm("ghi", 300)`, which happens to be `"emp3"` (class: `String`). They're different objects, hence the value printed is different.

You should override `toString()` in `TestEm` to see more clearly what's happening, something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return company + " " + salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fourth line is printed outside the loop and is the value returned from the map.

As you have overridden `equals` and `hashCode`, the new `TestEm` object you built is considered equal to the last one you added to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over the keys, not over the values.